# Python when appropriate to use try function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a bit of silly question, but could you advise me when it is appropriate to use try/except. I am working with API and create few functions, it looks something like this:

```
connection = connection to API

def request1:
    #do something

def request2:
    #do something

def request3:
    #do something
```

I was wondering should I use try/except for connection or should I use it for each do something? What would be the right way to use it?

Comment: You might benefit from Googling some documentation on working with exceptions in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it wherever something can go wrong. It is best to prevent every termination of your program because of an error. Use try, except to catch it and display a understandable message for the user. Then exit the program with another exit quit, but not a rough termination. Or ask for new input, a repeat etc.

Comment: So in my case it would be both connection and every do something, as each function could be unavailable as well as the connection to API could be unavailable itself?

Comment: The connection for sure, because there can go something wrong with connecting. For the functions it depends on which information they use and their requests. If something can go wrong because of wrong input or something you will need to catch it. If there can't go anything wrong except for a connection failure i would recommend you also catch that.

Comment: Thanks for you help. The only thing, which I can see about each individual function is that it can be suspended by the vendor for some period of time in this case I believe it would be good to use try. Anyway thanks a lot for clearing things up for me.